# Trying to run/install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, microcode

I'm trying to install/run Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB stick.
However, when trying to do so I'm told to update microcode to 0x22 or newer and that's how far I get.

When I try to google it it only shows me how to do this while in Ubuntu using the terminal. Obv. since I don't have Ubuntu installed that's not an option.

I updated my bios and when I enter the bios at startup it tells me that I have microcode version 19.

Would appreciate any help :)

My hardware is :
MB: asus z-97p
CPU: i5-4690K
G-card: msi gtx970 oc
RAM: Corsair Vengeance DDR3 1600MHz 8GB

Comment: It would be a bit of a hassle but couldn't you install Ubuntu 16.04 first, then update the microcode, then upgrade to 18.04?

Comment: I dont know, but i'll give it a go

Comment: Tried,but no such luck. I have however discovered that in my bios it claims that i have microcode patch 19. When checking microcode version in HWinfo and RWeverything it says that i have microcode version 24.